# Set buttons inline and break line to fit different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to add some buttons in a line and break it in a new line when they reach the end of the screen:

[image]

If you know CSS, what I need is similar to `display: inline-block` rule.

I am looking for a XML solution only, I want to avoid measuring the screen and buttons using java to emplace them below programatically.

This is my current code, the following buttons are inside a `ConstraintLayout`:

```xml
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="Imagen"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boton1"
        android:text="Play"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boton2"
        android:text="Audio"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boton3"
        android:text="Play"
        android:onClick="playVideo"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boton4"
        android:text="Youtube"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/boton5"
        android:text="Raw"        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since last time, I found this library that you should enjoy ! [github.com/google/flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

In your case, you should use the **flexWrap** attribute :

This attribute controls whether the flex container is single-line or multi-line, and the direction of the cross axis. Possible values are:

- nowrap (default)
- wrap (**use this**)
- wrap_reverse

You will be able to wrap your buttons.

[image]

**Installation**

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
}
```

**Usage**

FlexboxLayout that extends the ViewGroup like LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. You can specify the attributes from a layout XML like:

```xml
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_end"
        />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using gridLayout ?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Imagen"        
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Audio"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:onClick="playVideo"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Youtube"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Raw"
        />

</GridLayout>`
```