# Create lists with different types of items

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart

I would like to create a horizontal `listView` where the first item is always an + icon. After get image, it will move to second item and so on.

This is what I tried

```
  Container(
         color: const Color(0xFF00FF00),
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
         child: ListView.builder(
             scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
             itemCount: 1,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildRow();
                  }),
                      )

Widget _buildRow() {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.camera,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        getImage();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think that this answer can answer your problem. If you have time to change your strategy (Do not use listView) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57660505/7528285

Comment: @ZachBvy thanks, but I'm using dart language.

Comment: I don't know Dard :( I thought it was still possible to add libraries.

Comment: @ZachBvy is ok :)

Answer (score 1):

You could start your list of widgets with just the plus widget. And you add your following widgets on the first position of the widget using dart's insert funcion in lists. Something like this:

```
listWidgets.insert(0, yourWidget);
```

Doing that you plus widget always will be the last item of the list and will be displayed on the last position.

```
 Widget initialWidget = _buildRow();
 List<Widget> listWidgets = [initialWidget];
 Container(
     color: const Color(0xFF00FF00),
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
     child: ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         itemCount: 1,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return listWidgets[index]
     ),
                  )

Widget _buildRow() {
return IconButton(
  icon: Center(
    child: Icon(
      Icons.camera,
      size: 30.0,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    Widget yourWidget = <your-logic-to-create-widget>;
    setState(() {
       listWidgets.insert(0, yourWidget);
    })
  },
);
}
```

Comment: can you provide some example?

Comment: thanks,I have tried your answer, but not sure whether it will work or not. How can I put the selected image into listView?

Comment: I have updated some code, can I email you to check?

Comment: I'm new in stack overflow so i don't know if it against the rules or not. But if is nnot you can send me for sure

Comment: Can you give me your email?

Comment: rodrigobastosv@gmail.com

Comment: do you know how to solve ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953895/signature-in-flutter